# Is there an equivalent for {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom' in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

`import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';`

I'm currently using Nextjs,
I need help for an equivalent of **useLocation**

`

```
 import Link from 'next/link';
 import { FC } from 'react';
 import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
 import { useStore } from '../store';`



const PrivateRoute: FC = ({ children }) => {
const currentUser = useStore((state) => state.currentUser);
const location = useRouter();`

if (!currentUser)
    return (
        <Link
            href={`/sign-in?redirect=${encodeURIComponent(
                location.pathname + location.push('chat')
            )}`}
        />
    );
return <>{ children }</>
```

}

export default PrivateRoute;`

Answer (score 7):

#### Navigate

```
const router = useRouter()
const navigateTo = () => router.push('/dashboard/app')
```

#### Pathname

```
const router = useRouter()
console.log(router.pathname); // logs the current pathname
```

#### Get state from previous page

Page A:

```
const router = useRouter()
router.push({
  pathname: '/B',
  query: { result: JSON.stringify(result) }
});
```

on Page B:

```
const router = useRouter()
let result = JSON.parse(router.query.result);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use useRouter from 'next/router' and then you can either use pathname or asPath and then you conditionally add slug or params. Rest you can find more information via documentation posted by others.